# How to send a text message to someone who called me using Android 5.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

It seems to me like there should be a way to send a text message to someone who called without having to save that number in the contacts list, but I can't figure out how.
I'm using pure android 5.1.1 with default apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer, for Android 6:

1. On the `Phone` app, go to the tab with the clock icon (the middle tab).
2. Tap the number that called you.
3. On the drop down menu that opened below, tap `Send a message`.

### Original answer, for Android 5.1:

1. On the `Phone` app, go the `RECENTS` tab.
2. Tap the number that called you.
3. On the drop down menu that opened below, tap `DETAILS`.
4. Tap the three-dots-icon on the upper right of the action bar, and choose `Edit number before call`.
5. Tap the three-dots-icon to the right of the number, and choose `Send SMS`.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. If anyone finds any shorter way to do it, I would be interested to know.